# How to resolve \multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Smith1882}} inserting an unwanted space when using the cite package?

Tags: spacing, citing, multirow, cite-package

Using `\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Smith1882}}` in conjunction with the cite package `\usepackage{cite}` results in an unwanted space.  A minimal working example gives:

[image]

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c & \multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Smith1882}} \\
d & e & f & \\
\hline
g & h & i & \cite{Smith1882} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{temp}

\end{document}
```

BibTeX file:

```
@ARTICLE{Smith1882,
  author = {John Smith},
  title = {I'm {J}ohn {S}mith},
  year = {1882}
}
```

Removing the cite package gets rid of the problem, but obviously means I can't use the cite package.

**Question**: How do I resolve this problem?

I tried changing it to `&\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{Smith1882}}`, and I tried adding in unnecessary brackets `\multirow{2}{*}{{}\cite{Smith1882}}`, but these didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cite` package automatically inserts a space before the `\cite` command. This can be seen in `X\cite{Smith1882}X`. Apparently, the package fails to detect that the space should not be inserted in the `\multirow` context.

You could load `cite` with the `noadjust` option, but that will disable the feature everywhere. Alternatively, you can temporarily turn it off with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Smith1882,
  author = {John Smith},
  title = {I'm {J}ohn {S}mith},
  year = {1882}
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\citenoadjust{\let\cite@adjust\@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
a & b & c & \multirow{2}{*}{\citenoadjust\cite{Smith1882}} \\
d & e & f & \\
\hline
g & h & i & \cite{Smith1882} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
a\cite{Smith1882}b
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact the package also inserts space at the beginning of a paragraph, so maybe this is a more deep-rooted problem...